# Django Forms: dealing with un-validated request.POST

Tags: django, forms, validation

In short: I have a `model` with several fields, and on this `model` is a foreign-key field connecting it to to a `User` instance. Then, I have a `model-form(1)` that generates `HTML` for this model's fields, and that with a custom `ModelChoiceField-instance` that presents `UserProfile`-instances instead of `User`-instances. To validate the submitted information, I have a `form` (regular form) that validates that a `UserProfile`-instance was submitted. If it was, I update `request.POST` (through a copy of it), and validate against a second `model-form`(2) that exactly mirrors the underlying `model`.

This all means that I first have to pass a `request.POST` with a lot of un-validated information into a form that only validates part of it, then updated a `copy` of a *partially validated* `request.POST`, edit it, and then finally validate it again.

Is all of this safe? Is it considered bad practice/**unsafe** to pass a `request.POST` with a lot of information into a `form` that only validates one part of it? Additionally, is it **safe** to make a copy of a `request.POST` that is only partially validated - and then update it?

To what degree can you work with objects containing unsafe information, such as `request.POST`, without it becoming a problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post a snap of your `form1` and `form2` it will be easier to understand. 

Have you considered overriding validate method of `ModelForm` itself.

Comment: Hey! Seeing your comment now, I have already changed my approach. I opted to instead use a form (regular form) to validate all request.POST at once, which I hope should be fine. Still interested in learning about to what degree you can work with objects containing possibly unsafe data, if you happen to know anything about it!